# How to get the Lenght of argument declarated as a variant

Tags: vba

```
Function MyPV(CF As Variant, PositiveR As Double, NegativeR As Double)
    Dim n
    Dim i, soma
    
    soma = 0
    
    For i = 1 To n
        If CF(i) > 0 Then
            soma = soma + CF(i) / (1 + PositiveR) ^ i

        ElseIf CF(i) < 0 Then
            soma = soma + CF(i) / (1 + NegativeR) ^ i
        Else
            MyPV = "ERRO"
        End If
    Next i
    
    MyPV = soma  

End Function
```

In this code, I have to select the Cashflows and then return the present value. The book I'm using suggests doing CF as a Variant, but I can't get the value of its length. How can I do it?
[image]
I know that excel in English "," is used to separate the parameters of a function, but in Portuguese is ";"

Comment: `For i=1 to CF.Cells.Count` maybe

Comment: In VBA as Variant can hold an array.  In the context of excel you can get an array of values  'CF=<range>.value'.  If the range is a single column use  worksheetfunction.transpose otherwise you will get a 2d array representing a 1D array.  Once you have an array you can get the size of the array by using 'UBOund(CF)-LBound(CF)+1'.  In your case, as you don't use tthe index 'i' to reference anything other than ite,m in CF you would be better off using a for Each loop 'Dim myIten as Variant: For Each myItem in CF'.  then each use of CF(i) would be replaced by myItem.